# Print number of file and directories giving the path

Tags: c#, binary-tree

As the title said I'm looking for a way to print all the directories and files in a tree. I have a tree like this:

```
C:/
├── Program Files/
│   └── Word
└── Program Files (x64)/
    ├── Chrome
    └── Ink
```

My code goes through one branch and I cannot go back to enter in a new folder. For example, I able to make count in Chrome but I cannot came back to look inside Ink because my code end the iteration. Here  it is:

```
    private void countFiles(string directoryPath, string VmVsphereName, string restorePointID)
    {
        //Verifica autorizzazione sui dati
        Guid oidVm;
        using (TSCLOUDEntities context = new TSCLOUDEntities())
        {
            oidVm = (
                        from vm in context.VM10_MACCHINE_VIRTUALI
                        where vm.VM10_VSPHERE_NAME == VmVsphereName
                        select vm.VM10_OID
                     ).Concat(
                        from vm in context.NCL10_VIRTUAL_MACHINE
                        where vm.NCL10_VSPHERE_NAME == VmVsphereName
                        select vm.NCL10_OID
                     ).Single();
        }

        TipoPiattaformaCloud tipoPiattaformaCloud = Bll_VirtualMachines.GetCloudPlatfomOfVm(oidVm);
        VeeamCredential veeamCredential = Code.Config.Instance.GetVeeamCredential(tipoPiattaformaCloud);

        string veeamResponseHeader = GetVeeamResponseHeader();
        string veeamSessionId = GetVeeamSessionId();
        VeeamClient veeamClient = new VeeamClient(veeamCredential, veeamResponseHeader, veeamSessionId);

        if (href == "")
        {
            fileSystemEntries = CatalogUtility.GetFileSystemEntries(veeamClient, VmVsphereName, restorePointID, directoryPath);
            files += Directory.GetFiles(directoryPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count();
            directories += Directory.GetDirectories(directoryPath, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count();
        } else
        {
            fileSystemEntries = CatalogUtility.GetFileSystemEntriesByHref(veeamClient, href);
            files += Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count();
            directories += Directory.GetDirectories(path, "*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories).Count();
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < fileSystemEntries.Directories.Count(); i++)
        {
            try
            {
                path = fileSystemEntries.Directories[i].Path;
                href = fileSystemEntries.Directories[i].Href;
                var stepInside = CatalogUtility.GetFileSystemEntriesByHref(veeamClient, href);
                directories += stepInside.Directories.Count();
                files += stepInside.Files.Count();
                if (stepInside.Files.Count() != 0)
                {
                    foreach (var file in stepInside.Files)
                    {
                        space += file.Size;
                    }
                }
                if (stepInside.Directories.Count() > 0)
                {
                    countFiles(path, VmVsphereName, restorePointID);
                }
            } catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
            {
                continue;
                //Do nothing
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                log.Error(ex);
            }
            directories += fileSystemEntries.Directories.Count();
            files += fileSystemEntries.Files.Count();
            count += 1;
        }
    }
```

Hope I was clear. Thanks to everyone

Comment: im confused are you looking for a java or c# answer to this ?

Comment: I'm sorry @DevlinPaddock. It's for C#. Thanks for the question. I will editing it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

heres a sample that should recursively do that.

```
public static void RecursivePrintFiles(string Path, int TabDepth)
{
    int tabDepth = TabDepth;
    while (tabDepth-- > 0)
      Console.Write("\t");
    Console.Write(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Path) + "\r\n");
    IEnumerable<string> Directories = Directory.EnumerateDirectories(Path);
    IEnumerable<string> Files = Directory.EnumerateFiles(Path);
    tabDepth = TabDepth;
    foreach (string file in Files)
    {
       while (tabDepth-- > 0)
          Console.Write("\t");
       Console.Write(System.IO.Path.GetFileName(file) +"\r\n");
    }
  foreach (string Directory in Directories)
     RecursivePrintFiles(Directory, ++TabDepth);
}
private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string Path = "C:\\Users\\devlinp\\Downloads\\mlem";
    RecursivePrintFiles(Path, 0);
}
```

I find recursion is really helpful in cases like this. I would try to use this code as a starter and change it to have the formatting your looking for.

Comment: I really have problem with recursion even if I try to use it correctly. Thanks for the answer. I will work to adapt to my code and try it before gives you the correct answer!

Comment: One question @devlin. What is the object TabDepth?

Comment: @user9420152 i was using that variable to track how many tabs to add to the start ( so if the file or folder is 3 levels down it would indent 3 times) it could also be used to track how many times youve recursed through the function

Comment: I cannot know the deapth of my path cuz it changes each time. Do you think there is a way to know it knowing the path?

Comment: @user9420152 if you do it recursively you will track what depth your at as you go.

that function will output the files in any folder passed to it then it calls itself on any folder in that folder. incrementing its depth